# Using native mobile select while using select2

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-select2

I am using select2, but it has some issues on the mobile version of my website.
Naturally, if I simply change the element if agent is mobile, I encounter a lot of errors since my jQuery code is based on select2. 
So my question is, can I keep select2 as it is, but initiate the native select action on click? And if not, what would be the easiest way to go at it?

Comment: What kind of errors did you encounter?

Comment: I fixed the issue by replacing select2 with the native select box if agent was mobile, which looks and behaves much better on mobiles.